# Implement HTML CSS and Javascript Template in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I purchased a template which includes HTML, CSS, and Javascript files for a static webpage. I'm trying to use these existing files in my Angular project so I can connect it with a Nodejs app to make it a full stack webpage with backend. However, when I tried to put these files into Angular, everything is broken and is not functioning as it would when I manually open the HTML files on Chrome.

I've tried creating components for each HTML pages and adding the CSS and Javascript files into assets folder. Then I went on angular.json and added each CSS files into the styles array and the Javascript files into scripts array.

The HTML files look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Basic Page Needs
================================================== -->
<title>Hireo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/colors/blue.css">

</head>

<body>
.........body code...........
<!-- Scripts
================================================== -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/mmenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tippy.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/simplebar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/snackbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/counterup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you open dev tools in chrome, are there any errors / missing refs?

Answer (score 0):

In your `angular.json` file add the static .html files to the `assets` array with their respective paths. You can then access the files i.e `www.your-domain.com/your-static-file.html`

Answer (score 0):

Anything you put in your `assets` folder will be available to the application, just remember to provide the relative/absolute path including `assets`.

If you have files in other folders or have specific errors (e.g. in the Network tab in Dev Tools), please provide more details that so I can advise. Until then, you can find most common solutions in https://lukasznojek.com/blog/2019/03/angular-cli-different-ways-to-include-assets/.